# List without bullets, numbering, or alphabet

Tags: enumerate, multicol

I want to start writing simple non mathematics documents in LaTeX, but due to my state of beginner I hit on some problems.
Basically, I want to use enumerate without any numbering.

Is there a better way to do this.

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}


\begin{document}

\textbf{To be - Simple present}

\bigskip


\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{enumerate}
\item[] I am
\item[] I am not
\item[] am I?
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{enumerate}
\item[] you are
\item[] you are not
\item[] are you?
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{enumerate}
\item[] we are
\item[] we are not
\item[] are we?
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{enumerate}
\item[] they are
\item[] they are not
\item[] are they?
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: See also the `description` environment and enumitem package.  If you want simplicity, look at the outlines package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As table? Code is shorter and more clear:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} *{4}{X} @{}}
I am        &   I am not        &   am I?       \\
you are     &   you are not     &   are you?    \\
we are      &   we are not      &   are we?     \\
they are    &   they are not    &   are they?
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to make this simpler. Apart of the most obvious solution (tabular), you can also just leave one multicol environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\subsubsection*{To be - Simple present}
\hspace{\parindent}\begin{minipage}{.6\linewidth} % to indent the columns
\begin{multicols}{3}
\obeylines\parskip1em 
I am 
you are
we are
they are
I am not 
you are not
we are not
they are not 
am I?
are you?
are we?
are they? 
\end{multicols}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Another way could be use the `tabto` package. In this case tha columns widths can be different:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabto}
\TabPositions{\parindent,.3\linewidth,.54\linewidth}
\begin{document}
\subsubsection*{To be - Simple present}
\parindent4em
\parskip1em

~\tab I am 
\tab I am not 
\tab am I?

\tab you are
\tab  you are not
\tab  are you?

\tab  we are
\tab  we are not
\tab  are we?

\tab  they are
\tab  they are not
\tab  are they?

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your answer is more advanced for me right now. That's good, because I'll study it further. Thank you.